# multinode data read lock spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have multiple WAS nodes which poll a single database row at a defined frequency.
I want to lock the database row for read operation i.e. stop node02 from reading as soon as node01 starts reading.
Is there a way to achieve this by Spring?

Within spring integration, i have a poller, my config goes something like:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1800000">
             <int:transactional  isolation="SERIALIZABLE" propagation="MANDATORY"/>
    </int:poller>

</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Is there a way to handle this without DB level row lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked : 
@Transactional( isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)